# What's the best way to design a database for Z-Indexes of Elements

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first, z-index

I'm currently trying to create a CMS that allows users to edit Text Areas and Images in a PDF that allows them to move, scale, and change element z-indexes (bring in front, bring to back).

What's the best way to map out a database to consider for Z indexs.

I'm using Entity Framework Code First for this process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Code First, then you shouldn't worry about mapping out the database - EF is going to do that for you.

I'd suggest creating POCO's (plain old CLR objects) to represent each of your entities (Text Areas, Images). Then, add a property to each object for "Z index". I mean, it sounds like each object can have 1 and only 1 z-index, right?

Hope that helps. Scott Gu has a nice intro/tutorial:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx